# How to send object throgh request between diffent application

Tags: java, struts-1

I want to send Java (POJO class) Object to other applcation which is installed on diffent or same tomcat.

I have tried with `request.setAttribute("abc",javaObj)` but getting `null` value while using `request.getAttribue("abc")` and `scope="application"` and My both application on same tomcat.
I am Using redirect jsp.

Comment: check this :http://www.coderanch.com/t/365856/Servlets/java/cross-context-request-dispatching

Comment: other application or from one jsp page to other

Comment: You can't share objects as part of request between 2 separate JVM. You need to use Java RMI.

Comment: IMO, XML is the best way to share data between two different applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share a variable between two applications under the same tomcat then you need to set it in the servletcontext using setAttribute method of that.

For sending the POJO to a different tomcat or JVM, you either use RMI or HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Use RequestDispatcher and setAttribute

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("your url");
MyPojoObject m=new MyPojoObject();
request.setAttribute("abc", m);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

to retreive

```
MyPojoObject mo=(MyPojoObject)request.getAttribute("abc");
```